# Как запретить CKeditor оборачивать тег script в тег p?

Tags: jquery, javascript, ckeditor

Есть такой код:

```
var script = editor.document.createElement('script'); 
    script.setAttribute( 'type', 'text/javascript');
    script.setHtml('$(document).ready(function() { console.log("Скрипт вставлен"); });');   
    editor.insertElement(script);
```

В документ то вставляет, но почему-то в "р" элемент:

```
<p>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() { console.log("Скрипт вставлен"); });
</script>
</p>
```

И выдает ошибку:

```
ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    ...r e=[],b=this.getDocument().$.documentElement,c=this.$;c&&c!=b;){var d=c.parentN...
```

Answer (score 2):

По умолчанию, CKeditor создает новый **p** тег каждый раз, когда вы нажимаете **enter**.
Это можно изменить с помощью вот такой настройки, добавленной в конфигурационный файл:

```
// Вариант А
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_P;   // вставит <p></p>
// Вариант Б
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_DIV; // вставит <div></div>
// Вариант В
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;  // вставит <br/>
```

Возможно, поможет добавление такой настройки в конфигурационный файл:

```
config.fillEmptyBlocks = false;
```

**[Полный список настроек для CKeditor](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html)**

Плюс попробуйте использовать метод **editor.insertHTML** вместо **editor.insertElement**.

Либо, если это не поможет, попробуйте формировать содержимое вручную, с помощью следующих методов: **editor.getData** и **editor.setData**.

**[Полный список методов класса CKEDITOR.editor](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.editor.html)**